# fetching data from celery's backend(redis)

Tags: python, redis, celery

How do I get data(all I really need is the state of the task) from a Celery backend? I am using Redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you configured the CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND to use redis ( [see here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#conf-result-backend) ), then you can monitor your application using a variety of [methods](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html).

I believe that celeryctl should suffice..

Comment: Thanks but I found using celery.result suited my purpose more.